# Does my Z370 HD3P board have the Intel Management Engine?

Tags: central-processing-unit, chipset

I recently got a Gigabyte Z370 HD3P motherboard. How can find out if it has the Intel management engine on it or not?

One person told me it is on the CPU, but my understanding is that it is a secondary chip that is on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

It apparently requires a BIOS version that is didn't ship with for it to work, but the availability of a driver specifically for it suggests that it is there: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z370-HD3P-rev-10#support-dl

[Screenshot Driver download page on 3-5-18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwa7n.png)

Starting with 5 series chipsets it was embedded in the chipset itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine

Intel's support page on IME Verification tool suggests the same: 
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005974/software/chipset-software.html

To quote: "Currently, we support the following chipsets regardless of your system manufacturer or the motherboard in your PC:
Intel® Q57/H57/H55/P55 Express Chipset
Mobile Intel® QM57/QS57/HM57/HM55/PM55 Express Chipsets"

In newer chipsets it's been moved to the PCH, which is detailed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub

There doesn't seem to be a verification tool that is designed for newer chipsets, but the old one may still work.

Comment: The motherboard uses the Z370 chipset.

Comment: Updated answer to make my point in including the information about the verification tool more clear.